# Redshift this type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I run the first query all runs fine:

```
select uid,
(select top 1 city from UserData where UserData.uid = #uids.uid 
group by city)
from #uids;
```

The problem is when I add `order by count(city)`, I get an error: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

```
select uid,
(select top 1 city from UserData where UserData.uid = #uids.uid 
group by city
order by count(city))
from #uids;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `row_number()` in RedShift:

```
select u.uid, ud.city
from uids u left join
     (select uid, city, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by uid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from UserData ud
      group by uid, city
     ) ud
     on ud.uid = u.uid and seqnum = 1;
```

You might also try this in SQL Server as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your subquery is not working, which is obvious because you cannot use functions in ORDER clauses with SQL. You can only use them in SELECT and HAVING clauses.

If you want to order by `count(city)`, you should add it to SELECT clause with an alias and order by alias name. So your subquery can be like this:

```
(SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS city_count
FROM UserData
WHERE UserData.uid = #uids.uid
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY city_count
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: "because you cannot use functions in ORDER clauses with SQL". You might want to recheck your claim